# IFNULL() MySQL not working as expected in combination with ROLLUP

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query.

```
SELECT 
YEAR(Date) 'Year',
MONTH(Date)'Month',
SUM(Amount)'Amount' 
FROM Bill.Statistics 
LEFT JOIN Employees.Employee
ON Bill.Statistics.Employee = Employees.Employee.ID
WHERE Employees.Employee.Department LIKE '%%' 
AND Bill.Statistics.Employee LIKE '%%'
AND Date>='2020-10-01' AND Date<='2021-03-31' 
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date) 
WITH ROLLUP
```

This gives me a result of.

| Year | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 10 | 10.10 |
| 2020 | 11 | 11.11 |
| 2020 | 12 | 12.12 |
| 2020 | NULL | 33.33 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1.01 |
| 2021 | 2 | 2.02 |
| 2021 | 3 | 3.03 |
| 2021 | NULL | 6.06 |
| NULL | NULL | 39.39 |

Now when I try to use IFNULL() to get rid of the NULL's and just put a dash there I get the following result with the following code.

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(YEAR(Date), '-') AS 'Year',
IFNULL(MONTH(Date),'-') AS 'Month',
SUM(Amount)'Amount' 
FROM Bill.Statistics 
LEFT JOIN Employees.Employee
ON Bill.Statistics.Employee = Employees.Employee.ID
WHERE Employees.Employee.Department LIKE '%%' 
AND Bill.Statistics.Employee LIKE '%%'
AND Date>='2020-10-01' AND Date<='2021-03-31' 
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date) 
WITH ROLLUP
```

| Year | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 10 | 10.10 |
| 2020 | 11 | 11.11 |
| 2020 | 12 | 12.12 |
| 2020 | 12 | 33.33 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1.01 |
| 2021 | 2 | 2.02 |
| 2021 | 3 | 3.03 |
| 2021 | 3 | 6.06 |
| 2021 | 3 | 39.39 |

As you it just duplicates the last value from the previous into the cells where the NULL's were located.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
I just wanted all the NULL's to become simple dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the aggregated row of rollup (which generates those NULL values [according to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)) is generated "after" the selection of data. I think you should wrap the SELECT, like so:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(s.`Year`, 'Total Year') AS `Year`,
    IFNULL(s.`Month`, 'Total Month') AS `Month`,
    s.`Amount`
FROM

(SELECT 
    YEAR(Date) 'Year',
    MONTH(Date) 'Month',
    SUM(Amount) 'Amount' 
FROM Bill.Statistics 
    LEFT JOIN Employees.Employee
    ON Bill.Statistics.Employee = Employees.Employee.ID
WHERE Employees.Employee.Department LIKE '%%' 
    AND Bill.Statistics.Employee LIKE '%%'
    AND Date>='2020-10-01' AND Date<='2021-03-31' 
    GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date) 
    WITH ROLLUP
) AS s
```

Comment: This is exactly what was going on! Now I understand why it happens. Thank you for the quick response.